# Is $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ never injective?

Tags: calculus

I have an exercise to prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not an injective function, and, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, with n > m is also never an injective function. I made the proof with the 
Rank–nullity theorem, but I think there is a more intuitive way to see this fact

Comment: Since you mention the rank nullity theorem, are you assuming that $f$ is linear?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is a **linear** function?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't considered that, sorry, it was my mistake. The exercise doesn't say that $f$ is linear.

Comment: $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ both have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$. So there is a bijection between them. Does the exercise require that $f$ be continuous? If not, then the exercise is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Given no other restrictions on your function $f$, the exercise is incorrect as stated. $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ both have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, which by definition means there is a bijection between them. Hence there is an injective mapping with the hypotheses that you want.

(Rank-Nullity can only be applied if $f$ is linear, so it fails here.)

As requested in the comments, now consider the case where $f$ must be $C^1$. Then there is no injective map from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ is such a map. Then $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ must be connnected because it is the image of a continuous function. Since there are infinitely many elements in the domain, the image of $f$ is a nontrivial interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Now remove some point $a$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus a$ is still connected. But $f(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus a)$ cannot be connected since the image of $f$ was originally an interval. So the image of a continuous function of a connected set is unconnected, which is not possible. This proves our claim.

Comment: Maybe the information it's missing is that $f$ is $C^1$, does it changes something?

Comment: @Incognitex If $f$ is $C^1$ then indeed there is no such injection as requested.

Comment: Can you explain me why?

Comment: @Incognitex See my Edit.

Comment: Why assume $f$ is $C^1$? You don't use anything more than continuity...

Comment: David, is the information of the exercice, I forgot putting this into the question, sorry.

Comment: @Incognitex " is the information of the exercice": The exercise is still false as stated. There's an "edit" link - you can  _add_ the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous...

Answer (score 0):

If $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ is continuous then it cannot be injective.

**Hint:** We can certainly assume $f$ is not constant. Say $p,q\in\Bbb R^2$ and $f(p)<f(q)$. Choose $\alpha$ with $f(p)<\alpha<f(q)$. You can use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show there is more than one point where  $f=\alpha$. (Think about curves from $p$ to $q$...)